# Iron router: access route data in router function

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have a function that is called onBeforeAction that sets the session variable page title. I would like to assign it data that I am sending to the template. How can I access that data from the router?

I've tried something like this:

```
this.route('userPage', {
    path: '/profile/:userId',
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('singleUser', this.params.userId)
        ];
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            user: Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.params.userId}, {fields: {'username': 1, 'profile.friends': 1}})
        };
    },
    onBeforeAction: function() {
        Session.set('pageTitle', this.data.user.username); //THIS
    }
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here, `this.data` is a function. Give this a try:

```js
Session.set('pageTitle', this.data().user.username);
```

Comment: Of course. So it kinda works when you click on links but then breaks the navigation (if you click back button) for some reason...

Comment: Have a look in your browser console for errors. It may be that some part of that needs to be guarded like: `this.data() && this.data().user && this.data().user.username`